# How can I run an RxJava Observer on another thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio, rx-java

How can I run RxJava on another thread, as there's too much work on the main thread.

I have the Observer running inside a method, and here's a snippet of the code:

```
public void updatePie() {

RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(Functions.<Throwable>emptyConsumer());

Observable<Long> intervalObservable = Observable
        .interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      //.doOnError(Functions.<Throwable>emptyConsumer())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .takeWhile(new Predicate<Long>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(Long aLong) throws Exception {

                if (isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class) == false) {
                    RxB = false;
                }
                return RxB;
            }
        })
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Comment: subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) do this work. You also can use Schedulers.computation() or provide your custom scheduler

Comment: @ZSergei I changed observeOn to new Thread and kept subscribeOn to io, but the onNext only runs once. I tried observeOn computation as well and it's the same thing, only mainthread makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

`Observable.interval` by default work in background thread. so you don't have to do any thing.

`.subscribeOn()`  is responsible of where observable should work.

`.observeOn()` is responsible of where the following methods call should be work (usually MainThere)

Comment: But what if I want it to run on another thread than main? I changed observeOn to new Thread and kept subscribeOn to io, but the onNext only runs once. I tried observeOn computation as well and it's the same thing, only mainthread makes it work.

Comment: i'm no sure i got you,, but i see there is a confusion. subscribeOn & observeOn has no related how many onNext runs..they only tell where to work. you need to check your condition in `takeWhile` as it will stop emitting once it return `false`. check this URL for more about subscibeOn&observeOn https://proandroiddev.com/rx-java-subscribeon-and-observeon-a7d95041ce96